# Infopath form data submission

Tags: sharepoint-2013, infopath, sharepoint-designer

I am working on the sharepoint online where there is a form which has cross domain violence error.When i republish my infopath and click the link from there the data in the form is submitted but when i go the site and try to submit the data it shows the cross domain violence error.

Answer (score 0):

The updated Url from the infopath and The Url which you have in SPO should be same